# SceneKit: Un-pausing causes fps drop

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

So say my SceneKit Game is playing.
Then I hit the pause button which triggers..

```
mySceneView.isPaused = YES;
```

Then I wait a few seconds.
The FPS is now 0.
Then I press the un-pause button which triggers..

```
mySceneView.isPaused = NO;
```

Then the FPS climbs up from like 30 to 50 to the full 60.
This causes some in-game lagging, which looks bad.

Is there a trick to pausing to fix this issue?

Comment: Actual or simulator?

Comment: An actual phone, is being used for testing.

Comment: I don't quite know but maybe there is something to initialize the paused scene first, before un-pausing it. Check that.

Comment: I made a very simple test project. Just a spinning cube. http://pastebin.com/ZdDiE90a The issue still persists.

Comment: How are you measuring FPS? Sounds like you may be including the paused time (zero frames) in your calculations.

Comment: I have mySceneView.showStatistics set to YES. You can see the FPS being measured there.